# Onclick javascript not working file jsp java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jquery-ui

I have run on 2 env server websphere the same config 1 env error 1 env onclick working tab <kbd>f12</kbd> the same

if it is correct it must run into

`IndivBorrowerAction.do?event=prepare_update_income_info&BORROWER_ID`

This is code :

```
function editIncome(viewOnlyFlag,employmentStatus){
    
    if(viewOnlyFlag == 'true')
    {
        document.IndivBorrowerForm.action = "IndivBorrowerAction.do?event=prepare_update_income_info&BORROWER_ID="+getNameOrElements("cifId").value;
        document.IndivBorrowerForm.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        var basic =getNameOrElements('cifId').value;
        if(basic!=null && basic!="")
        {
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/IndividualCustomerAjax/checkSaveAllInfo",
                 data: { cifId: basic }, // parameters
                 //dataType: 'json',
                 cache: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                if(data==null)
                {
                    document.IndivBorrowerForm.action = "IndivBorrowerAction.do?event=prepare_update_income_info&BORROWER_ID="+getNameOrElements("cifId").value;
                    document.IndivBorrowerForm.submit();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data=="P")
                    {
                        alert("<%= alertSaveMsg %>");
                    }
                    if(data=="E")
                    {
                        alert("Please save employment details first");
                    }
                    if(data=="I")
                    {
                        document.IndivBorrowerForm.action = "IndivBorrowerAction.do?event=prepare_update_income_info&BORROWER_ID="+getNameOrElements("cifId").value;
                        document.IndivBorrowerForm.submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('<%= alertSaveMsg %>');
        }
    }
}
```

And tag `<a>`

```
<c:if test="${appType eq 'SE' and smeApplicantType ne 'JUR'}">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="editIncome('${viewOnly}','${IndivBorrowerForm.employmentStatus}'); return false;"><bean:message key="label.income"/></a></li>
            </c:if>
```

2 tab <kbd>f12</kbd> the same

[image]

Please help me, I can't find any error here

Comment: Hi what is `getNameOrElements` ?Also what doesn't work ? Please elaborate

Comment: Please provide more clear details about the issue. What do you expect to happen? What is happening? What errors are appearing in the console?

Comment: This is getNameOrElements <input type="hidden" name="cifId" value="20201104012913">

Comment: I have run code on 2 env server websphere the same config 1 env but error 1 env onclick working tab f12 the same